# Duplicate column name 'NULL' while importing the csv

Tags: mysql, csv

I try to import file in mysql but every time it give me error of Duplicate column name 'NULL'
Kindly check the image for more [image]

Comment: The last 5 column names are `NULL`, so there must be something wrong with your CSV file. Could you add that as well, so people can help you better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your csv  file by deleting the column from the right most after your last column.
or
Copy all your column fields data to a new file then save as csv.